# Send email using gridview checked employees to them in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, email, gridview, checkbox

Good day

I have grid view with employee data displaying in it.

```
      <asp:TabContainer ID="tcmanagers" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
                    Width="100%">
        <asp:TabPanel ID="TabAdmins" runat="server" HeaderText="Admins" TabIndex="3">
                        <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" CssClass="style3"
                        ForeColor="Blue" Width="290px">Select Admins to send:</asp:Label>

                         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                         <asp:Button ID="Sendadmins" runat="server" Text="Send Email" Width="201px"/>
                         <br />
                         <br />
                         <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Employee_ID"
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" Width="633px" CssClass="grd">
                         <Columns>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee_ID" HeaderText="Employee_ID" ReadOnly="True"
                                   SortExpression="Employee_ID" Visible="False" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee_Number" HeaderText="Employee Number" SortExpression="Employee_Number">
                         <ItemStyle Width="70px" Wrap="False" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee_Surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Employee_Surname">
                         <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee_Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Employee_Name">
                         <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee_Job_Title" HeaderText="Job Title" SortExpression="Employee_Job_Title">
                         <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee_Dept" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Employee_Dept">
                         <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee_EMail" HeaderText="Email Address" SortExpression="Employee_EMail">
                         <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                         </asp:BoundField>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check All"><HeaderTemplate>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAlladmin" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkAllAdmin_CheckedChanged" />
                         </HeaderTemplate>
                         <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdmin" runat="server" />
                         </ItemTemplate>
                         </asp:TemplateField>
                         </Columns><RowStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" />
                         <EditRowStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" /><HeaderStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt"
                             Font-Underline="False" CssClass="grdhead" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                             <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grdalt" />
                             <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Fuchsia" />
                             </asp:GridView>
                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
                                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT  dbo.lms_Employee.Employee_ID,dbo.lms_Employee.Employee_EMail,dbo.lms_Employee.Employee_Number, dbo.lms_Employee.Employee_Surname, dbo.lms_Employee.Employee_Name, dbo.lms_Employee.Employee_Job_Title,dbo.lms_Employee.Employee_Dept FROM dbo.aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN  dbo.aspnet_Users ON dbo.aspnet_Membership.UserId = dbo.aspnet_Users.UserId INNER JOIN  dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles ON dbo.aspnet_Users.UserId = dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles.UserId INNER JOIN   dbo.lms_Employee ON dbo.aspnet_Users.UserName = dbo.lms_Employee.Employee_UserName WHERE     (dbo.lms_Employee.Employee_Active = 'True') AND (dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles.RoleId = '9ec9b26d-64a1-4736-8e82-fe6de7c7caac') and Employee_Number <> '100'">
                                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                          </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:TabPanel>
                </asp:TabContainer>
```

Now I can select all data in it or one at a time with code below.

```
Protected Sub chkAllAdmin_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    For Each gr As GridViewRow In GridView3.Rows
        Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(gr.FindControl("chkAdmin"), CheckBox)
        If DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Checked Then
            cb.Checked = True
        Else
            cb.Checked = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

What I want to do is send a email to all the selected employees. I have an iis server and sql server. So my database is on sql server and my web application is on iis server.

I have no idea how to approached this any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without coding it for you, here's the strategy I use for this type of task:

1. Convert the BoundField items to TemplateFields.  When you do this, you'll likely have controls with meaningful names inside the ItemTemplate for each field, like  "lblEmployeeEmail"
2. On your button-click, loop through the items in the GridView and for each row, use the FindControl() method to find the CheckBox (and then check if it's checked) and use the FindControl() also to get any other fields you might need. (The email label, etc.)

Here's the generic code pattern to follow (lifted from [learneveryday.net](http://learneveryday.net/asp-net/gridview-asp-net/how-to-loop-through-gridview-rows-gridviewrow/)):

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
{
   CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("CheckBox1");
   if (CheckBox1.Checked)
   {
      // we write this code for find a label value
      Label lblLookFor = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblLookFor");
      string lookfor = lblLookFor.Text;
   }
}
```

Of course, this only covers how to get the employees that are checked and how to retrieve their email address from the GridViewRows.  I'm assuming you already know how to send emails, but if not, see [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).